# Get isFinishing worked inside the Service

Tags: android

I am trying to pass a context from my `MainActivity` to the `TrackingService` class to check the method `isFinishing()` inside the `onDestroy()` in the TrackingService but I am getting `The method isFinishing() is undefined for the type Context`

How can I get `isFinishing()` working inside the service?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {
    private static Context mContext;

     public static Context getContext() {
            return mContext;
        }

}
```

**TrackingService:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(lm != null && MainActivity.getContext().){
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            System.out.println("ABC TrackingService lm was removed.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("ABC TrackingService lm locationManager is null.");

        }       
    }

}
```

**Edit**

I am trying  to remove the locationManger of my TrackingService class when the app is being closed and not when the user switches the activity

Is there anyway to distinguish between the both cases when the `onDestroy()` is being called?

I have a trackingService `locationManager`  component which processes in the background and it is launched from the `MainActivity` activity. At the same time, I have another component to retrieve this data from the server and displaying it in the `Map` activity. The user can access this data in the server from the MainActivity, when he clicks a button in the MainActivity, then the alarmManager with the InsentService class starts retrieving data from the server to display it in the Map activity.

I am trying to remove the `locationManager` in two cases:

- When the user click the checkbox in the menu of  MainActivity.
- or when he closes the app (Not when the user changes the activity).

How can I distinguish whether onDestroy is being invoked cause the user cloeses the app or when it being called when the user switches between the activities?

I appreciate any help.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {
    TrackingService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route_available);
        // Start the TrackingService class.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        startService(i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        System.out.println("test onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.checkable_menu);
        checkable.setChecked(isChecked);
        return true;
    }

    // Start and stop the background service.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.checkable_menu:
            if (isChecked = !item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(isChecked);
                Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
                startService(i);
                System.out.println("test if onOptionsItemSelected");
            } else {
                mService.stopTrackingService();

            }
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
    stopService(i);

    }

}
```

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
    LocationManager lm;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        detectLocation();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private void detectLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside detectlocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                this);
        enableGPS(lm);

    }
    @Override
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(wifi_receiver);
    System.out.println("ABC TrackingService onDestroy() was invoked.");

    if(lm != null){
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        System.out.println("ABC TrackingService lm was removed.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("ABC TrackingService lm locationManager is null.");

    }       
  }
public void stopTrackingService(){
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
  }
}
```

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
 // To stop the service when the user closed the app in the background and the map ativity was opened.      
        stopAlarm();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        stopService(i);
        System.out.println("ABC Map onDestroy() was invoked!");

    }
}
```

Comment: `isFinishing()` is a method of `Activity` not `Context`. Imo, it does not make any sense to call it in a service. What are you trying to check with `isFinishing`?

Comment: @SaschaKolberg: I want to check it to prevent removing the locationManager when the user switches from the MainActivity to the Map activity. The locationManger must just removed when the user closes the app. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Why do you think the service is stopped when you switch activities?

Comment: Also it is always stoped when I do the following : Go from MainActivity to Map Activity (service still work). When I go back (the service still works) but when I go again to the Map activity the service is destroyed and `locationManager` is removed.

Answer (score 0):

`isFinishing()` will only tell you whether of not a Activity is finished instead of just paused. If your service is destroyed before the activity `isFinishing()` might still return `false` despite the app being ended.

Your `Service` will not be destroyed just because you switch to another activity. It should run independently of your activities until either you stop it or it gets dumped by the system to free resources. If you want to prevent the system dumping your service, you can return `START_STICKY` in its `onCreate`.

If you want to kill the service when the application is ended by the user, could stop it in the `onDestroy` method of your main activity and there checking whether or not the activity is finishing:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    AsyncTaskCallback {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (isFinishing()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
            stopService(i);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

After clarifying some about what you would like to have, here is another option that might work for you:

You only start the service in your main activity. You never call `stopService` anywhere in your code. However, you `bind` the service to both activities and `undbind` in the `onDestroy` method of each activity. See [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). The service should be stopped when all bindings have been released.

Comment: Ok I have more text and code to the probelm. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I have tried that before. The onDestroy() in the MainActivity is just called when I close the app. The poroblem is with the `onDestroy()` in the `TrackingService` class is being called when I go from MainActivity to Map Activity (service still work, service onDestroy() is not invoked). When I go back (the service still works) but when I go again to the Map from the MainActivity  the service is destroyed and locationManager is removed because the onDestroy() of the TrackingService was invoked.

Comment: @Mr Asker I don`t clearly understand all your algorithm, but I think you shouldn`t call stopService() in onDestroy of MapActivity.

Comment: @kolombo: but I want to stop the service when the user closes the app with opened map activity.

Comment: @MrAsker What exactly do you mean by *close*. Do you have a menu entry for closing? Because when the user leaves the app by *back* or *home* button, the app is not really close

Comment: @SaschaKolberg: no I dont have entry for closing I mean when the user closes the app in the background with the home button.

Comment: Then the app is not closed. It is in the background and user might want to return to the app after just checking something in another app. If you do not have a truly pressing reason to release the service in background, I would let android worry about it. Because the service will be stopped by the system when you app is idle for some time.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg: I mean closing the app with the home button in the background (Killing the app). If the user does that then he has to click the start icon again to start the app(He can access the app in the background anymore)

Comment: In this case all non-sticky services of your app will be stopped anyway

Comment: but it is not being stopped when I switch between the activities twice (it is strange behaviour.) also it is stoped when I kill the app with the MainActivity direct after starting the app. It is stoped when I start the app and go MainActivity->Map activity and I kill the app in the background with open Map. It stoped when I go MainActivity->Map activity -> MainActivity and I kill the app in the background with open MainActivity (but in this case, the onDestroy of the MainActivity is not being invoked.).

Comment: It did not stoped when I go Main->Map->Main->Map and I kill the app in the background with open Map activity since in this case `onDestroy()` of the map activity is being invoked.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg: I am calling stopService(i) in onDestroy of the MainActivity and map!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88293/discussion-between-sascha-kolberg-and-mr-asker).